# Swift/Xcode why does only first row have subtitle?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Can't figure out why every row except the first row doesn't have the subtitle text. The cell's main textLabel is working for all rows.

Could I have hooked up the outlets wrong or changed a setting in Storyboard?

p.s. - I'm a beginner level programmer, sorry if my code is pretty unorganized and scattered.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewSelectedShedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let db = Firestore.firestore()

var shedInfo = [[String:Any]]()
var styleType = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "\(styleType) Sheds"

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    db.collection("\(styleType.lowercased())_sheds").order(by: "stock_id", descending: false).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting Documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let id = document.documentID
                let size = document.get("size")
                let style = document.get("style")
                let rto_price = self.formatPrice(p: document.get("rto_price") as! Double)
                let cash_price = self.formatPrice(p: document.get("cash_price") as! Double)

                self.shedInfo.append(["id": id.uppercased(), "size": size!, "style": style!, "rto_price": rto_price, "cash_price": cash_price])
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return shedInfo.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(String(describing: shedInfo[indexPath.row]["id"]!))"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(String(describing: shedInfo[indexPath.row]["size"]!)) / \(String(describing: shedInfo[indexPath.row]["style"]!))"

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

func formatPrice(p: Double) -> String {
    let price = p as NSNumber
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency

    let nprice = formatter.string(from: price)
    return nprice!
}

}
```

Comment: Post your code please ...

Comment: Move the `tableView.register` line to `viewDidLoad`.